# Background gradient overlay with background-attachment:fixed

Tags: css

I have a section (full screen width) with a background set up this way :

```
.mysection {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
background-image:background-image:linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 500px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 800px), url(/my-background-image.webp);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: auto 100vh;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In other words : my background image is the height of the screen, and an unknown width. I apply a gradient on top of the image so as there is a smooth transition between the background color and the image (I do not want to use background-size:cover because my images will be much taller than wide)

**Problem** : the width of the image is unknown: it will depend on the image (not always the same one, some much wider than others).

**Is there any way to start the gradient at the exact position where I would see as much of the image as possible, without seeing the image right border?**

I don't think it's possible, so eventually I put the background image in a ::before element, to which i give a fixed width :

```
 .mysection {
background-image:none; 
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
} 

.mysection::before {
    content:"";
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
background-image:linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 300px), url(/my-background-image.webp);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The problem is : the gradient doesn't appear. If I put it "to right", it works fine. If I remove "background-attachment:fixed", it works.

So I understand that when background-attachment is on fixed, the gradient starts from the right of the position:relative element (or even the body, i'm not sure)?

Here is a jsfiddle with the issue : https://jsfiddle.net/3x9frj1L/
In this fiddle, the gradient appears because it is set from left to right. If changed from right to left, it won't appear. I'm starting to

Comment: Yes, the reference point for fixed background images is the viewport. So I don't think there is any way to achieve what you want, _without_ knowing the aspect ratio of the background image upfront.

Comment: This could be done with a child element containing the image (with the gradient applied relative to that child), but I don't believe a single element with a background image can do it.